# Exit function On Linux

Tags: c, linux, exit

When reading/writing a file in my application, I want to exit(1) if the file is not closed correctly. On Windows it works well, but on Linux this error appears:

```
‘exit’ was not declared in this scope
```

How can I solve that?

Thanks.

Comment: apparently it was C, retagged

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If this is in C, did you  `#include <stdlib.h>`?

Answer (score 6):

If this is C++ you have to include cstdlib:

```
#include <cstdlib>
```